# Nav Bar Movement When Adding Margin to Different Container

Tags: html, css, node.js

I am attempting to create a container that has variable amounts elements within it and currently creating the style sheet for that page. However, when I add a margin to that container, it seems to move the navigation bar that is fixed on that page and I have no idea why. I have been trying to fix this for a couple days now and have no idea what is the cause behind this. Here is the project repo: https://github.com/halsheik/RecipeWarehouse.git. Below are code that has been edited/added and is not updated in the repo as well as images demonstrating what is going wrong.

```
<%- include('../_partial/_header'); -%>

    <div id="recipesContainer">
        <div id="myRecipesContainer">
            <label id="myRecipesLabel">My Recipes</label> 
    
            <a href="/recipes/createRecipe" id="newRecipeButton">+ Create New Recipe</a>
        </div>
        
        <div id="allRecipes">
            <% recipes.forEach(function(recipe){ %>
                <% if(recipe.author == user._id){ %>
                    <div class="recipeContainerIndv">
                        <img src="/uploads/<%= recipe.recipeImageFileName %>"/>
        
                        <a class="reipeTitle"> <%= recipe.recipeName %> </a>
                        <!-- <% recipe.directions.forEach(function(direction){ %>
                            <a><%= direction %></a>
                        <% }); %> -->
                    </div>
                <% } %>
            <% }); %>
        </div>
    </div>
    


<%- include('../_partial/_footer'); -%>
```

```
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#recipesContainer{
    /* positioning of container */
    margin: 0% 5% 0% 5%;

    border: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
}

#myRecipesContainer{
    /* style of items within container */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    /* positioning of container */
    margin: 12px 12px 0px 12px;
}

#myRecipesLabel{
    /* style of items within container */
    font-size: 24px;
}

#newRecipeButton{
    /* positioning of container */
    margin-left: 16px;
}

.recipeContainerIndv{
    /* positioning of container */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 12px 12px;


    border: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 5px;
}

.recipeContainerIndv .reipeTitle{
    /* positioning of container */
    display: block;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;

    /* style of items within container */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2vw;

    border: solid;
    border-color: purple;
    border-width: 5px;
}




.recipeContainerIndv img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image: screen without added margin]
[image: screen with added margin]

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: I noticed your header partial contains closing body and html tags. Is that normal?

Comment: I am not sure. I believe I may have added them while editing, however, I did not notice them having any effect on my pages. I did remove them just now and there was still no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your "partial" header is a full html document, which is what @Nate-G was getting at. This article will help you I think https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application.

Your _partial/_header file should only really include the `<nav>` portion of the document. You have inverted the pattern so your partial contains a complete document, when it should be, as the name implies, only a part of the page.

You could have a partial for myRecipes and then a full myRecipes page that includes both the partial header and the partial for myRecipes that you included above.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think i've understood your question well, but judging from the title and the pictures i think you should simply apply `top: 0;` instead of `margin-top: 0;` to the fixed nav in your css file.